# Run a tensorflow with a list of fetches does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm playing around with Tensorflow and implemented a k means clustering algorithm. Everything works well, but if I want to run the session with a couple of fetches in a `list` I always get the error, that a `list` can not be converted to a `Tensor` or `Operation`.

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) explicitly says, that I can call `Session.run()` with a list. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is the source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def tf_k_means(k, data, eps_=0.1):
    eps = tf.constant(eps_)

    cluster_means = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
    tf_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='data')

    model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    expanded_data = tf.expand_dims(tf_data, 0)
    expanded_means = tf.expand_dims(cluster_means, 1)
    distances = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sub(expanded_means, expanded_data)), 2)
    mins = tf.to_int32(tf.argmin(distances, 0))

    clusters = tf.dynamic_partition(tf_data, mins, k)
    old_cluster_means = tf.identity(cluster_means)
    new_means = tf.concat(0, [tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(cluster, 0), 0) for cluster in clusters])

    clusters_moved = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sub(old_cluster_means, new_means)), 1)
    converged = tf.reduce_all(tf.less(clusters_moved, eps))

    cms = data[np.random.randint(data.shape[0],size=k), :]

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(model)
        conv = False
        while not conv:
            #####################################
            # THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT WORK: #
            #####################################
            (cs, cms, conv) = sess.run([clusters, new_means, converged], 
                                        feed_dict={tf_data: data, cluster_means: cms})    

    return cs, cms
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument [<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:1' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:2' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:3' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>] of 
[<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:1' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:2' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>, 
<tf.Tensor 'DynamicPartition_25:3' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>] has 
invalid type <class 'list'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not 
convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.dynamic_partition` returns a [list of Tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#dynamic_partition), so `clusters` is itself a list.

```
clusters = tf.dynamic_partition(tf_data, mins, k)
```

When you feed that list into sess.run inside another list, I think that's where you have your problem. you could maybe try:

```
sess.run(clusters + [new_means, converged], ...
```